# NVM on WSL2: cannot install Node, version not found

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvm

I installed WSL from the Microsoft Store onto Windows 10. I was able to succesfully install NVM onto this using the curl command as documented on https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

NVM installs, I can run commands and check the version.

However when I try to install node, either a specific version like `nvm install 12.18.1` or `nvm install` or `nvm install --lts` I get a message that the version is not found

```
me:~$ nvm install 12.18.1
Version '12.18.1' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.
```

or

```
me:~$ nvm install --lts
Installing latest LTS version.
Version '' (with LTS filter) not found - try `nvm ls-remote --lts` to browse available versions.
```

If I try to run `nvm ls-remote`, after several seconds I get `N/A`

I have installed this before on MacOS and on a different non-work Windows 10 box and have not seen this behavior before.  It's like it is not hitting the nodejs server.

Thoughts?

Comment: A few thoughts - `nvm cache dir` to check the location, then verify your user has access.  Also, `nvm cache clear` (hail Mary).  Also, might create a new temp user, launch into it with `wsl ~ -u tempuser`, and try installing it there.  If it works there, then at least you know it's something in  your default user profile that's causing problems -- it's not a "system" problem, at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had experienced the same issue on a work laptop running WSL2. It was caused by a proxy/firewall solution (ZScaler) installed on the PC which was blocking connections to nodejs.org. To test is this is the issue you can run the command below to see if it runs successfully

```
curl -I --compressed -v https://nodejs.org/dist/
```

The solution for me was to run a VPN on my PC which would bypass that restrictions of the corporate proxy and allow me to download the node versions required. Alternatively you can work with your IT department to have nodejs.org   unblocked.